# Make dataframe having different column length with the given lists of different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists of different length and i want to form a DataFrame having these lists as columns of a DataFrame. 
Lets say my lists are 
    `L1 =["a","b"]` 
    `L2 = ["g","h","o","y"]`
    `L3 = ["k","u","e"]`

i want a dataframe in which looks like

```
 L1 L2 L3
 a  g  k
 b  h  u
    o  e
    y
```

The question is just not limited for only three columns.It is in the range of hundreds

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to ask?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Following results, it might be looking for, the idea is to convert the list into Data frame, you could also create a function that take as input, list arguments and not type every list into Data-Frame by hand.

#### Example 1:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

## your list
L1 =["a","b"] 
L2 = ["g","h","o","y"] 
L3 = ["k","u","e"]

## Convert List into DataFrame 
L1 = pd.DataFrame(L1)
L2 = pd.DataFrame(L2)
L3 = pd.DataFrame(L3)

## Concanate the created DataFrames and Fill 'NaN' with or empty spaces 
db =pd.concat([L1,L2,L3], ignore_index=True, axis=1).replace(np.nan, '')

## Results
print(db)
```

#### Example 2 (Function passing list arguments):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

## your list
L1 =["a","b"] 
L2 = ["g","h","o","y"] 
L3 = ["k","u","e"]

## function passing arguments
def wrapper(*args):
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in args], ignore_index=True, axis=1).replace(np.nan, '')


## Results
print(wrapper(L1,L2,L3))
```

Comment: Well what if i have say 100 lists and i need to do for all

Comment: If you have 100 list you could write the following notation: wrapper(L1,L2,L3......Ln). thus you could loop over the function and join together the list, i.e., the *arg parameter allows you to pass any amount data into the function. hence it will do the DF concatenation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) iterator from `itertools`. It will pad the shorter sequences with `fillvalue` which is `None` by default. You can specify something else like an empty string in the example below.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
df = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(L1,L2,L3, fillvalue=''), 
                  columns=['L1','L2','L3'])
```